# How to change the image on page refresh

Tags: image, onchange, page-refresh

I want to change the set of 5 image on page refresh called in html.
    the images should called this under the body tag:

```
 <img src="images/side-logos/1.jpg" alt="">
 <img src="images/side-logos/2.jpg" alt=""> 
 <img src="images/side-logos/4.jpg" alt=""> 
 <img src="images/side-logos/5.jpg" alt="">
```

I want to called the set of images under the body tag not in javascript.
  I have searched a lot on website but everyone calling the image in javascript not under   the body tag.
  So Please help me if anyone has the solutions for it.

Comment: http://lorempixel.com/400/200/ Check this. new mage every time you refresh :) :)

Answer (score 3):

just replace onclick event with window refresh event

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
    <img id="image" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Randomize!" onClick="randImg()" />
```

**JS**

```
var images = [
    "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-18.jpg",
    "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-19.jpg",
    "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-20.jpg",
    "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-17.jpg"];

function randImg() {
    var size = images.length
    var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
    document.getElementById('image').src = images[x];
}

randImg();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFft7/)

**EDIT**
[new_demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EpnTH/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunateley, you can only do this with javascript.

To do that, here is some code that is placed in the  tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Randomize() {
    var images = new Array("one.jpg","two.jpg","three.jpg","four.jpg");
    var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById("divid").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";
}

window.onload = Randomize;
</script>
```

The name of the images shoukd be in the images array and the "divid" is where you want the images to appear.